# Calling a jQuery method at declaration time, and then onEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been writing JS (mainly jQuery) for quite a few months now, but today I decided to make my first abstraction as a jQuery method. I already have working code but I feel/know that I'm not doing it the right way, so I come here for some enlightenment.

Note: Please do not reply that there's already something out there that does the trick as I already know that. My interest in this matter is rather educational.

What my code is intended to do (and does):

Limit the characters of a textfield and change the color of the counter when the user is approaching the end.

And here's what I have:

```
$(function(){

  $('#bio textarea').keyup(function(){
    $(this).char_length_validation({
      maxlength: 500,
      warning: 50,
      validationSelector: '#bio .note'
    })
  })

  $('#bio textarea').trigger('keyup');

})


jQuery.fn.char_length_validation = function(opts){

  chars_left = opts.maxlength - this.val().length;

  if(chars_left >= 0){
    $(opts.validationSelector + ' .value').text(chars_left);

    if(chars_left < opts.warning){
      $(opts.validationSelector).addClass('invalid');
    }
    else{
      $(opts.validationSelector).removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }
  else{
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, opts.maxlength);
  }
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<div id="bio">
  <textarea>Some text</textarea>
  <p class="note>
    <span class="value">XX</span>
    <span> characters left</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Particularly I feel really uncomfortable binding the event each on each keyup instead of binding once and calling a method later.

Also, (and hence the title) I need to call the method initially (when the page renders) and then every time the user inputs a character.

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the binding and initial triggering in the method:

```
jQuery.fn.charLengthValidation = function(opts) {
    return this.keyup(function() {
        var charsLeft = opts.maxLength - $(this).val().length;
        if (charsLeft >= 0) {
            $(opts.validationSelector + ' .value').text(charsLeft);
            $(opts.validationSelector).toggleClass('invalid', charsLeft < opts.warning);
        } else {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, opts.maxLength));
        }
    }).trigger('keyup');
}

$(function() {
    $('#bio textarea').charLengthValidation({
        maxLength: 25,
        warning: 10,
        validationSelector: '#bio .note'
    });
});
```

Comment: Very elegant. I appreciate it!

Comment: In any way, you should return `this`!

Comment: I changed the example to include that.

Answer (score 2):

`chars_left` is a global variable which is not good at all. Here is a better (slightly changed) version:

```
jQuery.fn.char_length_validation = function(opts) {
    this.each(function() {
        var chars_left = opts.maxlength - $(this).val().length;
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            chars_left = opts.maxlength - $(this).val().length;
            if (chars_left >= 0) {
                $(opts.validationSelector).text(chars_left);   
                if (chars_left < opts.warning) {
                    $(opts.validationSelector).addClass('invalid');
                }
                else {
                    $(opts.validationSelector).removeClass('invalid');
                }
            }
            else {
                $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, opts.maxlength));
            } 
        });
    });
    this.keyup(); // makes the "initial" execution
    return this;
};
```

See a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3tnzd/).

Some explanation:

- In a jQuery plugin in function, `this` refers to the elements selected by the selector. You should use `this.each()` to loop over all of these and set up every element accordingly.
- In this example, every element gets its on `chars_left` variable. The event handler passed to `keyup()` has access to it as it is a closure. **Update:** It is already very late here ;) It is not necessary to declare it here as you recompute the value every time anyway. Still, it should give you an idea how to have private variables that persist over time.
- You should always `return this` to support chaining.

Further thoughts:

- You might want to think about how you could make it work for several textareas (i.e. you have to think about the validation selector). Don't tie it to a specific structure.
- You should have default options.
- **Update:** Of course you can make your plugin work with only one textarea (like some jQuery functions work).

Comment: In this current example `this.each()` looping isn't really necessary, right? And each element doesn't really need `chars_left` variable because that can be scoped to keyup event handler as well?

Comment: Very useful answer, combined with Heikki's one it gave me a much better understanding of the subject. Too bad I can only accept one. Thank you!

Comment: @Heikki: Well if you want to make it universal you better use `this.each`. If *I* would be creating a plugin I would make sure that it works also if multiple elements are selected. But yes you could put `chars_left` in the event handler, but only because you recompute it very time. Still it shows a way how to have private variables.

Comment: @Felix: That's what I thought too, except that shouldn't "just an event handler" case work with multiple elements too? It binds to those elements and triggers initial event.

Comment: @Heikki: Of course in this case it is perfectly fine for just the event handler.... maybe I complicated things too much ;)